# Loading modules with importlib if file and directory has the same name

Tags: python-3.x, file, import, directory

*Hey Guys ;),*

I have a question about loading modules with importlib. Currently I have the following code:

```
import os
import importlib 
 
Module = "Testumgebung::Defaults"   # Example 1 : WORKS     
Module = "Config::Test"             # Example 2 : DOES NOT WORK

Module_FH = Module
Module_FH = Module_FH.replace( '::' , '/' ) + '.py'

if( os.path.exists( os.getcwd( ) + "/" + Module_FH ) == False ) :        
    print( f"[  ERROR  ] The Specified Module '{Module}' Could Not Be Found !" )
 
Module_Instance = importlib.import_module( Module.replace( '::' , "." ) )
```

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
[ VTE ]
|--> Config
       |--> Testpy
|--> Testumgebung
       |--> Defaults.py
VTE.py
Config.py
```

When I import the modules in the 'VTE.py' file with the following code:

```
Module_Instance = importlib.import_module(Module.replace( '::' , "." ) )
```

does this work for the 'TestEnvironment::Defaults' module

With the module 'Config::Test' I get the following error message, probably because the file "Config.py"
already exists in the file structure :

```
Module_Instance = importlib.import_module( Module.replace( '::' , "." ) )
  File "D:\Anwendungen\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 981, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Config.Test'; 'Config' is not a package
```

Can someone please help me here.

How do I make it load the "Config\Test.py" file with importlib even though the Config.py file already exists in the root directory.

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards
NumeroUnoDE

Comment: As you are missing an `__init__.py` file in the Config directory, python treats it as a [namespace package](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=namespace%20package#namespace-packages). This gives the `Config.py` a higher priority when importing. A fix would be to add `__init__.py` to the Config directory (Which then shadows `Config.py`). [A similar thing was done in pytest](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/commit/19dda7c9bdc8ef71c792e0f77a9595bfad8d9248) to vendor `py`.

Comment: Thanks, the __init__.py  was really missing. It works now, but if i add the '__init__.py' to the folder 'Config', the Config.py in the root directory will not be loaded correctly anymore :-(

Comment: I already explained why. Either your namespace package gets shadowed by the file, or the package shadows the file

Comment: I now tried a few things but unfortunately it doesn't work.
I added a __init__.py to the Config subdirectory, but afterwards
my instance , i get with :

Self.Module_Instance = importlib.import_module( Self.Module.replace( '::' , "." ) )

is empty :(

Comment: You tried something? What exactly?

Comment: I already sent you the code. Please look at my thread 'Using Object Manager To Load & Manage Custom Modules ( OOP )' :)